# How to get multiple elements of an ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

In python I want to access the values of some element(s). Particular, I have the following structure extracted in a local variable `msg`:

```
        <timestamp>2019-01-08T03:45:30-08:00</timestamp>
        <stage>QUEUE</stage>
        <text>Added to NSG run queue.</text>
```

I just want to print the content. The following code is working

```
print(msg.find('timestamp').text, msg.find('stage').text, msg.find('text').text)
```

but it looks like extreme overhead. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Expected output:

```
('2019-01-08T03:45:30-08:00', 'QUEUE', 'Added to NSG run queue.')
```

Comment: There is a `findtext` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext

Answer (score 0):

Try xmltodict. That gives you add values as the dict's `values()`.

```
import xmltodict

s = """<xml>
          <timestamp>2019-01-08T03:45:30-08:00</timestamp>
          <stage>QUEUE</stage>
          <text>Added to NSG run queue.</text>
          </xml>
  """

print(", ".join(xmltodict.parse(s)['xml'].values()))
```

Comment: I consider that even more complicated as you have to use another module. The `findtext` suggestion looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Seems what u want was contents of all labels, which can use the standard lib `re` to achieve that.

```
import re

exp = '>(.*)</'
print(re.findall(exp, msg))
```

Comment: I consider that even more complicated. The `findtext` suggestion looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `msg` element to get its children. This produces the wanted output:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

XML = """
<msg>
  <timestamp>2019-01-08T03:45:30-08:00</timestamp>
  <stage>QUEUE</stage>
  <text>Added to NSG run queue.</text>
</msg>"""

msg = ET.fromstring(XML)

print(tuple(c.text for c in msg))  # Tuple
print([c.text for c in msg])       # List
```